# Height of standalone font-awesome icon in Bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I've varying heights on Bootstrap buttons, where the button contains *only* a Font Awesome icon.

Here's what it looks like in my app:

[image: Font Awesome icon buttons with different heights]

The button group on the left is 34px high, the one on the right is 28px high.

However I don't see the same issue when using Bootply or such, e.g.: http://www.bootply.com/BKDSnIXVQH . Here the icons are the same height.

So I must be doing something wrong, but I cannot diagnose it!

In the Chrome element inspector, there's a spacing at the top and bottom of the left-hand button text, but no such spacing around the `fa` icons on the right. The `padding-` styles are the same for both buttons so I don't know where that spacing is coming from. `line-height` and `font-size` are all the same.

If I add some text to the `fa` buttons they return to the correct height.

Given I haven't provided enough for a reproducible example, I don't expect anyone to answer this, but how can I at least diagnose what the problem is?

Comment: see if there is a height property for either. and if that is different. As you said without the code and relevant css its hard to say. You can inspect and see computed properties of each. and then track down where the differing height is set from.

Comment: There's no height explicitly set, for any of the the elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `.fa` class has a `line-height: 1;` instead of using bootstraps 1.41.... for specific cases you can make use of something like this

```
.force-parent-lh {
  line-height: inherit !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify and change the font-size in the fa button.

Comment: The `font-size` is the same in both... do I misunderstand? Are you suggesting I should increase it in the `fa` button? I didn't think I should have to do that.

Comment: yes..its correct for line height.We take all CSS properties is inherit into text.so line-height,font properties are important for get same height of the icon buttons.